# INNER JOIN from another INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with 3 tables :

- PM_FLX_ENTE
- PM_ST
- PM_ANO_SP

and I would like to get PM_ANO_SP.L_ANO_SP for certain values of PM_ANO_L.L_ANO which contains a code number with '/'.

```
SELECT COUNT(RF_INTRN),TRIM(pm_st.c_st),TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO)
    FROM PM_FLX_ENTE
    INNER JOIN PM_ST ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ST = PM_ST.C_ST
    INNER JOIN PM_ANO_L ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ANO = pm_ano_l.c_ano
    WHERE pm_flx_ente.C_ANO <> '0000'
        AND pm_ano_l.c_lang = 'FR'
    group by TRIM(pm_st.c_st), TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO)
ORDER BY COUNT(RF_INTRN) DESC
```

[image: sql query result and pm_ano_sp table]
Can you help me please

Comment: Your query shouldn't work.  You specify that the database has three tables, but the query references four.  I'm as confused as the database, not really having any idea what you want to accomplish.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: What's not working?  Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing an error of some sort?

Please note, that when you do multiple inner joins, the previous join conditions have to be true for the other joins to work.

I.E

```
INNER JOIN PM_ST ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ST = PM_ST.C_ST
```

Has to evaluate true in order for the below to work

```
INNER JOIN PM_ANO_L ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ANO = pm_ano_l.c_ano
```

To solve this, you may want to change your INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs

```
SELECT TRIM(pm_st.c_st),TRIM(pm_ano_l.L_ANO),COUNT(RF_INTRN)
        FROM PM_FLX_ENTE
        LEFT JOIN PM_ST ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ST = PM_ST.C_ST
        LEFT JOIN PM_ANO_L ON PM_FLX_ENTE.C_ANO = pm_ano_l.c_ano
        LEFT JOIN PM_ANO_SP ON PM_ANO_L.L_ANO = pm_ano_sp.l_ano_sp
            WHERE pm_flx_ente.C_ANO <> '0000'
            AND C_LANG = 'FR'
            and pm_ano_l.L_ANO like '%/%'
        GROUP BY pm_st.c_st,pm_ano_l.L_ANO
```